# Reactjs overide markdown types with react-markdown

Tags: reactjs, markdown

I am using contentful to get markdown to a react component that uses react-markdown to parse the markdown

```
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';

    <Markdown source={text} />
```

Would I like to do is to override the Renderer so instead of it rendering ## as an h2 render i can pass a custom component to override the default h2 type to my own h2 component. How can i do that and is there and examples?

Comment: I hadn't seen this library and it suits one of my immediate needs perfectly, so thanks for that :)

Answer (score 14):

One of the options to `<ReactMarkdown>` is `renderers`.

One of the [common renderers](https://github.com/rexxars/commonmark-react-renderer#type-renderer-options) handles headings. If you look at the [default rendering](https://github.com/rexxars/commonmark-react-renderer/blob/master/src/commonmark-react-renderer.js) you'll see this:

```
heading: function Heading(props) {
    return createElement('h' + props.level, getCoreProps(props), props.children);
},
```

So pass in your own `heading` handler. Check the level inside, roughly:

```
function CustomHeading(props) {
  if (props.level !== 2) {
    return createElement(`h${props.level}`, getCoreProps(props), props.children);
  }
  
  return <MyCustomElement {...props} />
}
```

If you don't have access to the code that commonmark-react-renderer gives you in the context of your function (which you probably won't) then you'd also need to duplicate what `createElement` gives you (but it's simple).

---

Unrelated: I've never used `<ReactMarkdown>` (but will), but this took me about five minutes of research. I'm including my path to encourage others to dig into their own questions and hopefully give some insight into how such things can be researched.

1. The [react-markdown](https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown) home page
2. Scanned through the "Options" section to see if custom rendering was trivially supported
3. Found the `renderers` option, which sounded promising
4. Clicked [the link](https://github.com/rexxars/commonmark-react-renderer#type-renderer-options) provided in that option's docs
5. Saw that `heading` was one of those (which made sense; I'd expect a renderer for every major formatting that Markdown supports)
6. Opened up the `src` directory to see if the implementation was easy to find
7. There was only one file, so I opened it
8. Searched the page for "heading" and [found it](https://github.com/rexxars/commonmark-react-renderer/blob/master/src/commonmark-react-renderer.js#L50)
9. Cut and pasted that code here

The ability to read docs and follow trails is really important.

Comment: Dave Newton, thanks for the insight into your problem-solving process.